# Get all combinations of a list in Haskell without using List Comprehension

Tags: list, algorithm, haskell, combinations

So, i managed to get all possible combinations from a list using list comprehension:

```
reorganize :: String -> Int -> Int -> [String]
reorganize _ _ 0 = []
reorganize y 1 _ = [y]
reorganize (a:as) len xs = map (\x -> a : x) (reorganize as (len-1) (len-1))
                       ++ reorganize (as ++ [a]) len (xs-1)

permute :: String -> [String]
permute x = reorganize x len len
          where len = myLength x
```

However, i would like to know how to do it without using list comprehension.

Comment: Btw, the function "myLength" is only a function identical to the regular Length function, i just had to implement it myself to this exercise.

Comment: You are not using list comprehension.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem in the 4th line "(\x -> a : x)" isn't list comprehension?

Comment: no, list comprehension is something like `[f x | x <- xs]`: https://wiki.haskell.org/List_comprehension

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem oh Well, so i guess my question is answered... haha thanks!

Comment: `\x -> a : x` is a *lambda expression*.

Comment: and permutations are not combinations.

Comment: Oh, okay, i totally forgot about the diferences between combination and permutation, so it is the possible permutations, right?